# IE8 Kills my Jquery script

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

The following script works fine on Firefox, but fails on IE8 and I'm not sure why. What's supposed to happen is after I click a thumbnail image, a whole series of animations executes. Instead, the thumbnails disappears and nothing else happens. I ran it through the I8 Developer Tools debugger; it didn't trigger any errors, though the jquery.min file did. Am I missing some IE8 related quirk?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#back').hide();
        $('#full-wrap').hide();
        $('#thumb-wrap a').children().not('img').hide();//hide image captions

        moveIt = $('#thumb-wrap').outerWidth(); //Get the width of the thumb-wrap div

        $('#thumb-wrap a').click(function(){

            var $big = $(this).index(); //get 0-based index of the thumb that was just clicked
            $('#ajax-content > h1').hide();//hide the page title
            $('#thumb-wrap').hide(); //hide the thumbnails
            $(this).children().not('img').clone().appendTo($('#gallery-wrap')).wrapAll('<article/>').delay(600).fadeIn(); //Clone the image captions and wrap them in an article
            $('#back').fadeIn(500); //make the back button appear

            $('#full-wrap img').eq($big).siblings().hide(); //Hide all fullsized images that don't match the index of the clicked thumb
            $('#full-wrap img').eq($big).show(); //reveal fullsized image that does match the index of the clicked thumbnail

            $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '+=' + moveIt * .5 + 'px', 'left': '6%'}, 'slow');
            $('#full-wrap').show(100).animate({ 'right': '+=' + moveIt * .75 + 'px'}, 'slow'); //slide out by a distance equal to the width of thumb-wrap.

        });

        $('#back').click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();//hide the back button
            $('article').remove();//remove the article div
            $('#full-wrap').animate({'right': '0', 'opacity' : 'toggle'}, 400);//hide the fullsize image div
            $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': moveIt, 'left' : '43%'}, 400);
            $('#thumb-wrap').delay(500).fadeIn(500);//reveal the thumbnails
            $('#content > h1').delay(500).fadeIn(100);//show the page title

        });

     });
</script>
```

[Here's the live site](http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/textiles/) So you can see what I mean. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you replace `.5` and `.75` with `0.5` and `0.75` ? Also, please don't minifi URLs, I won't click on it because it obfuscates my destination.

Comment: @user257493, I added the full URL to the original question. And I just tried adding the zeroes before the decimal. No difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `var` when declaring `moveIt = $('#thumb-wrap').outerWidth();`....IE isn't very tolerant of this, and it's good practice to always declare your variables explicitly anyway.  It should look like:

```
var moveIt = $('#thumb-wrap').outerWidth();
```

By *not* using `var` you're *trying* to say "declare this as a global variable", e.g. `window.moveIt`...but IE doesn't play that game, it'll just throw it back at you :)

---

Also, there's *another* IE<9 issue, `.wrapAll('<article/>')`...since IE doesn't support this element you can't natively use it here, you'll need something like [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to get this working older IE versions.

Comment: Yup,a global variable is exactly what I was trying to declare. I added the var back in...no, still no go. :(

Comment: @qp2wd - you have *another* issue, this: `.wrapAll('<article/>')`, IE8 doesn't support this element...so you can't use it and expect it to work here :)

Comment: Do they have statues dedicated to you where you come from, sir? They need to. Thanks so much; that was exactly the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using IE9 and its developer tools.  There are lots of nulls/undefined variables getting trapped when I trap on all errors.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the variable not being properly declared as a user above mentions. Run it and see if they're still there. They may well be; this marks my first real foray into the depths of jquery, so I'm sure my code is hacky at best.